# Modeling of a transaction storage in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

Wondering if anyone can point me to a good direction with Cassandra data modeling question for my use case.

Assume we have a concept of a session, within that session various transactions occur that are described by some metadata. Transactions could be deleted or updated within a given session. So in other words:

Session ID:

- Transaction A -> {metadata A}
- Transaction B -> {metadata B}  ...
- Transaction B' -> {updated metadata B}  ...
- Deleted Transaction A  ...

There are multiple ongoing sessions with OWN lists of transactions and metadata.

The requirements are:

1. to query by Session ID + Transaction ID to fetch transaction metadata
2. to list all transactions in a given Session ID

The obvious solution that comes to mind is to use Session ID for partitioning and Transaction ID as a clustering key.

However, this does not seem to be a good idea because the number of transactions could be large (let's say millions), metadata per transaction is also not small (let's say 10KB), deletes of transactions are also frequent. I am afraid if I go with clustering solution the row could become very wide and due to deletes also full of tombstones.

Has anyone ever had to model something like that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bit hard. Tombstones are something you have to fight against to, but you can't live without them...

If you can delete entire sessions with their transactions then you could try to alleviate a bit the tombstone thing by creating a *dynamic schema* model where you basically create dynamically a table for each new session and store there everything pertaining that session. That's because a table truncation or drop do not cause tombstones. Beware that you should not create *too much dynamism* on your schema because the distributed nature of C* could bring you down (eg a node being rebuilt could take much longer than your "table switch", failing miserably, and you're still wondering why). You'd get stuck and lose data.

Maybe if you're interested only to the most recent million rows (eg only the rows of the latest 5 days) then you could create 6 tables, one for each *active* day and one for the *oldest* one, with whatsoever partitioning and clustering configuration, and truncate the oldest table, avoiding tombstones and deletes. It really depends on your use case.

---

**EDIT**

You should be able to control the "wideness" of your rows by simply counting transactions in a particular session:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    session_id bigint,
    transaction_id bigint,
    splitter bigint,
    transaction_count bigint static,

    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY ((session_id, splitter), transaction_id)
);

CREATE TABLE counters (
    session_id bigint,
    splits counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

Here I took an hypotetical `session` table and added a `splitter`, fields which will be used to `break` the wideness of your rows, and a static field `transaction_count` which will keep track of how many transactions there are in each partition. Then you would keep track of how many `splits` you have on each session.

Just to be more clear, the first time you'd insert data like this:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 0, 0, 1, ...);
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 0, 1, 2, ...);
...
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 0, N, N+1, ...);
```

When you reach your **N**, be it 10.000 or 50.000 keys, you "switch" partition by creating a new "splitter":

```
UPDATE counters SET splits = splits + 1 WHERE session_id = 0;
```

and then keep inserting data with:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 1, N+1, 1, ...);
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 1, N+2, 2, ...);
...
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, splitter, transaction_id, transaction_count,...) VALUES (0, 1, 2N, N+1, ...);
```

So the insert was easy. To retrieve all of your stuff you simply do:

```
SELECT splits FROM counters WHERE session_id = 0;
```

and it will return a number **M** which will tell how many "splits" there are in the session. Then you'd:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = 0 AND splitter = 0;
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = 0 AND splitter = 1;
...
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = 0 AND splitter = M - 1;
```

If you need to extract a single transaction, however, you'll need to find it, so in the worst case you'll need to run **M** queries. Unless you create a "reverse" table that will tell you in which "split" you'd have to look at...

Hope I was clear enough...

Comment: The tombstones is not the only concern here. Even if we didn't have deletes at all the size of the row could become substantial - too wide.

Comment: You have the power to control how big your rows actually are. Just add something *important* to your partition key (eg the day of the session) and you're done.

Comment: I don't think it s that simple. Date (or date bucket)  is irrelevant in this application - the query will have to be across all available dates. Coming up with a fixed number of hashes/buckets is an option but is not bullet proof as the number of transactions is unpredictable. So let s say we come up with 10 buckets and add that hash to the partition key. There will not be any guarantees that that will be enough. Plus, when querying you have to query all buckets one by one. Btw this hash approach is something we are currently doing.

Comment: This is a good idea provided you can autoincrement transactionID, if that was possible then you would not even need transaction count, as you could just divide transactionID/(# of transactions per bucket) to immediately identify the bucket. Counting transactions is a tricky part .. i guess you could use the lightweight tranactions but that table would become really hot as every insert would hit it.

Comment: @SergeyT You should need to count transactions only during writes. So can't you count transactions at application level?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the options is to use a Materialized View to be able to query by the session id. The rest of the transaction operations would directly manipulate/access the transaction table.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    session_id     bigint,
    transaction_id bigint,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY ((session_id, transaction_id))
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW session as
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE session_id IS NOT NULL,
    transaction_id IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id, transaction_id);
```

The only problem I see is that there is no way to guarantee the consistency on the materialized view as it will be "eventually consistent" asynchronously. Reading it might not be up to date.